# SQL Server - Write log to a table when executing stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, logging, stored-procedures

I want to `insert a log record to a table` when i execute a `stored procedure`.

Firstly,

I created a table with 3 column named:

> ID(AUTO INCREMENT),MESSAGE(VARCHAR), CREATED_ON(DATETIME)

Secondly I wrote a procedure:

```
 create  PROCEDURE        DO_LOG(@MSG_IN VARCHAR) 
 as
 BEGIN

 INSERT INTO test.dbo.TB_ETLLOG(MESSAGE,CREATED_ON) 
 VALUES(@MSG_IN,GETDATE());
 END;
```

I want to write log when executing another procedure so i use this:

```
EXEC DO_LOG @MSG_IN ='Start DO_ACCOUNT_AML'
```

But it doesn't write log to table. Is there any mistake in my code? Thanks.

Comment: There is no problem with procedure code. Please check the user has access to the database or write permissions on target table, etc. Don't you get any message or error? You can also run SQL Profiler and catch what is exactly running on the database. OR with high probability the calling SP code does not work as you expected and does not call the do_log procedure

Comment: @Eralper I think that i have full access to database. As above, i just want to insert a log to table with value"Start DO_ACCOUNT_AML" for "MESSAGE" and "Current time" for "CREATED_ON".

Comment: What happens if you execute "EXEC DO_LOG @MSG_IN ='Start DO_ACCOUNT_AML' " as a stand-alon command? Could you see a new entry in the table? By the way, you might set a length for the input msg_in variable like varchar(100), etc since it is a single character right now

Comment: Bear in mind that if there's an open transaction when `DO_LOG` is called then the data won't be committed until that transaction is (and similarly, a rollback will erase it).

Comment: @Eralper I've forgot to set length for msg_in.. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can create a logging stored procedure that you can add to your code:

Create table:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log](
        [LogID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [LogTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        [LogAction] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [LogNote] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_CourionLog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [LogID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
```

Create Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddLog] 
        @LogAction varchar(50), 
        @LogNote varchar(max), 
        @LogTime datetime = null

    AS
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

            if @LogTime is null
                set @LogTime = getdate();

            INSERT INTO Log(LogTime, LogAction, LogNote)
                Select @Logtime, @LogAction, @LogNote 

    END
```

Usage:

```
DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @tmpCount INT;
SET @tmpCount = 1
SET @msg = 'Completed LastName Check: ' + cast(@tmpCount as varchar(10))
EXECUTE [dbo].[AddLog] 'INFO', @msg

EXECUTE [dbo].[AddLog] 'ERROR', 'This is an error message.'
```

See log messages:

```
select * from [dbo].[Log]
```